# Recursive Folders in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, home-folder

In my Windows 10 machine, somehow, I have a recursive folder structure like this:

```
C:\Win2008SP1
C:\Win2008SP1\C:\Win2008SP1
C:\Win2008SP1\C:\Win2008SP1\C:\Win2008SP1
```

[image]

I checked "C" drive or "Win2008SP1" folder is not a symbolic link or junction.

```
C:\>dir 
08/09/2020  07:40 PM    <DIR>          Win2008SP1 


C:\Win2008SP1>dir 
08/09/2020  07:40 PM    <DIR>          .
08/09/2020  07:40 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/26/2019  07:12 PM    <DIR>          C:
```

I don’t want to apply any delete command here since it may empty my C folder where windows and other software are installed. I only want to unloop the folders. Also, I can’t rename Win2008SP1 folder.

I feel this exact question may has been answered before and I am missing something. I appreciate if someone can redirect me to my desired exact question or point out the solution here.  I looked at these solutions [link1](https://superuser.com/q/416351/1207569) [link2](https://serverfault.com/q/667062/587303) [link3](https://superuser.com/q/78434/1207569), but my case is not exact match since “C” folder itself is in the loop.

Comment: Seems like the first thing to do is run `chkdsk /f`. But what you describe sounds like a junction point to me. How do you know it’s not? Did you use `dir /al c:\\` to see if the folder is listed.

Comment: https://www.solarwindsmsp.com/blog/refs-vs-ntfs

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar case myself, where it was clearly caused by disk corruption.

Any attempt in your case to delete the item may cause great
destruction of the disk.

My solution in my case was to rename the bad folder and ignore it until it was
time to change the computer or the disk. I counsel you to do the same.

Running `chkdsk /f` may fix the problem, but might also destroy the disk.
In my case I decided not to play Russian roulette with it.

I suggest to check the SMART data of the disk, to check if the disk is failing.
If it's in good health, then you may decide whether you can ignore the problem
or not.