# How to execute batch script in windows right?

Tags: windows, batch-file

According this answer in [How do I delete a folder which is nested quite deep and avoid “File name too long”?](https://superuser.com/a/256130/299131), I created `1.bat` file with following source:

```
@echo off
if not (%1)==() cd %1
for /D %%i in (*) do if not %%i==_ ren "%%i" _
pushd _ 
%0 
popd
```

I put this file near the folder which I want to delete.

[image]

I click on `1.bat`

and see following:

```
.....
Access is denied.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Access is denied.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Access is denied.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Access is denied.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Access is denied.
The system cannot find the path specified.
Access is denied.
....
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: Are you running the script as Administrator? Have you checked whether you have ownership of the folder and all its sub-folders?

Comment: Now I repeated all steps one more time and I see following result **Access is denied.
'1.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Comment: Yes I tryed to execute as admin

Comment: You mustn't execute the script as administrator as the default script path becomes `C:\Windows\System32` when running it as administrator.

Comment: You should try [taking ownership of the folder and all its sub-folders](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff404240.aspx) before running the script.

Comment: http://cdn.joxi.ru/uploads/prod/2014/10/03/7b8/7fd/f6bc90bb09aef943a63831b9aaf4838ebac62b98.jpg

Comment: And are you listed as the current owner of the folder as well as its subfolders?

Comment: I clicked as on picture for root folder

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. But are you listed as the current owner of the folder? And do you see `Full Control` in the `Access` column for the Principal you're a member of (e.g. `COMPUTERNAME\Administrators`)

Comment: I think yes http://joxi.ru/zWUuVIwyTJDPAgT-K_k

Comment: The screenshot shows that `Authenticated Users` have `Full Control` privileges. It doesn't show the privileges for the `Administrators` group. However, assuming you got it right, try running the script again (not as Administrator). If you still see the "Access is denied" error, it could mean you haven't yet properly taken ownership. Alternatively, try running the command prompt as Administrator and follow this guide to [take ownership of folders recursively](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-silently-recursively-take-ownership-of-a-folder-and-sub-folders-in-command-prompt/).